# On Ubuntu 19.10 VLC causes freezing and eventual app crash when video paused for longer than 5 minutes

Tags: video, vlc, freeze, 19.10

Whether I'm playing a long video playlist or just one video, when I pause VLC for longer than 5 minutes the system will keep freezing for several seconds and then unfreeze for several seconds, continuing this cycle until eventually the app crashes after about 10-15 minutes. When it's frozen, I can't use the mouse or keyboard, but any input is registered after it unfreezes. Besides this issue, there are no playback issues with VLC before a long pause, no stuttering or AV sync issues.

I ran `vlc -vv --logfile=vlclog.txt` in the terminal and [here is the log](https://www.codepile.net/pile/qeomKQz4)

This is the output in the terminal:

`VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: yes
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f3bf800bfc0] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using the mpeg4_unpack_bframes bitstream filter without encoding but stream copy to fix it.
[mpeg4 @ 0x7f3bf8e4f480] Video uses a non-standard and wasteful way to store B-frames ('packed B-frames'). Consider using the mpeg4_unpack_bframes bitstream filter without encoding but stream copy to fix it.
Aborted (core dumped)`

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3.3Gi       8.8Gi       322Mi       3.5Gi        11Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi


sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness=10
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I edited my question per your request.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You *may* have caused this by changing vm.swappiness=10. I have mine set that way too. However, your RAM/swap requirements might be different with your VLC problem. Set vm.swappiness back to 60, and lets see what happens. Monitor `free -h` and see if the numbers change radically from what you show above. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema `shared` fluctuated between 302mi-307mi, nothing else did and the problem persists.

Comment: This was with vm.swappiness=60? I'm more interested in `buff/cache` and `Swap used` and `Mem used`. Also show me `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: @heynnema Correct, that was in ref to vm.swappiness=60 and nothing else changed at all besides `shared`. Do you want me me to edit my question to show the entirety of `sudo lshw -C memory` or post a codepile.net URL since it's a bit long? BTW I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: For lshw output, you can use paste.ubuntu.com if you like. I strongly suspect that this is a VLC problem. Can you play the same videos using the `Videos` application? See https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=151957 for a similar case.

Comment: @heynnema Here's the `lshw` info: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mPybVCmzC2/)....that VLC forum post is actually mine :)...but I haven't received a response, I screwed up and initially posted the terminal output and not the log & one of the devs pointed that out and I amended it, but I think I missed my window...

Comment: Desktop or laptop? What's your model #? I want to check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema Laptop. Lenovo Y50-Y70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partial answer...

Lenovo Y50-Y70

Your BIOS is very old. You have version 9ECN31WW(V1.14) from 2014.

[This web page](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-touch-notebook-lenovo/downloads/ds100998) shows version 9ECN43WW(V3.03) is current.

Please verify that I have the correct web page for your model #, and then download and install the newer version and see if it helps.

**Note: Do a proper BACKUP of your important files BEFORE performing the BIOS update.**

Comment: That was the correct BIOS. I updated it and it's running better now. After initial BIOS update I left VLC paused for an hour with no freezing at all, that's never happened before, I've tested it every day for 10 days now. But then I restarted my laptop and it started freezing very shortly after pausing VLC. I just restarted my laptop for a third time and VLC has been paused for about 30 minutes so far and no freezing. Right after I finished the prior sentence it started freezing. But it's still a big improvement.

Comment: @coyote.foxtrot You may wish to reset the new BIOS to the default setup values... minding if there are any that need a custom setting for your setup. We may still wish to play with swap and vm.swappiness. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!